# Parameterize chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a recipe in chef, which I want to use multiple times (in multiple roles), only with a few parameters different. I want to be able to use multiple such roles on the same node.

How can I "parameterize" the recipe? I can't use attributes, because those are on node, so one role would override another's attributes.

Answer (score 3):

Recommended approach in this case is to use a lightweight resource provider or similar.

I think when the runlist is converged it dedupes any recipes so if you had 6 roles all including the same recipe and added each role to the runlist it would only actually run that recipe once.

[Seems like someone asked opscode this before](http://lists.opscode.com/sympa/arc/chef/2011-10/msg00203.html)

Brief introduction to LWRP's can be found [here](http://docs.opscode.com/chef/lwrps.html), althought that is more executing than creating a new one.

In this case once you have the LWRP you can either create one recipe which calls it multiple times or individual recipes for each call.

You could look to leverage the data model hierarchy of the node to build some sort of object that represents the instances of this you want to run and loop it that way.

Comment: I used definitions, but will look into LWRP too. Thank you.

Comment: No problem we did this for installing some of our internal products. There was a set of common steps that we needed to do for each of them so we defined a resource defining the parameters that we would want to be able to change and then defined an :install action and then have a number of recipes that do the install for us. We did that rather than the automatic install of many objects to keep the runlists readable and easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer very useful in helping me with a similar use case.  I wanted to share a simple example of creating an object to iterate over that PatrickWalker refers to ("...build some sort of object that represents the instances.. and loop...").  I hope this may help someone.

1. Create an attribute with a value which is a JSON string containing an array for each iteration and each array entry containing the parameters for each iteration.
2. Iterate over this array in a recipe performing an action using the parameters from the JSON string (you can encapsulate re-usable code in a definition or a LWRP).

## Simple Example

Creates one or more files with specific names and contents defined in JSON:

Attribute:

```
default['config'] = '{"files":[{"name":"/tmp/file_1","content":"file contents 1"},{"name":"/tmp/file_2","content":"file contents 2"}]}'
```

Recipe:

```
config = JSON.parse("#{node['config']}")
files = config['files']

files.each do |file|
  file "#{file['name']}" do
    content "#{file['content']}"
  end
end
```

You can extrapolate this simple example into your own use case.